# Can't set up Code Coverage with Jest. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs, vscode-extensions

As the title says, I'm trying to set up Jest to show me the cove coverage inside VSCode for my NodeJS projects. However, I can't seem to get it working. My code is not lid up based on the coverage levels and I really don't know why.

Following the official jest documentation, I set my **settings.json** as:

```
{
    "workbench.iconTheme": "easy-icons", 
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Atom One Dark", 
    "editor.tabSize": 2, 
    "[typescriptreact]": { "editor.defaultFormatter": "rvest.vs-code-prettier-eslint"     }, 
    "jest.coverageColors": { 
        "covered": "rgba(9, 156, 65, 0.4)", 
        "uncovered": "rgba(121, 31, 10, 0.4)", 
        "partially-covered": "rgba(235, 198, 52, 0.4)",     
    }, 
    "[json]": { 
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"     
    }, 
    "[typescript]": { 
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "rvest.vs-code-prettier-eslint"     
    }, 
    "jest.runMode": { 
        "type":"on-demand", 
        "coverage": true   
    }, 
}
```

Here's a simple example of my code which does not light up based on the code coverage:

```
class UserController {
 async getUsers(req:Request, res:Response){ 
   try{ const users = await UsersService.getUsers(); 
     return res.json(users);     
   }catch(error){ 
     return res.status(500).json(error);     
   } 
  } 
}
```

[image: Not lighting up code screenshot 1]